# Adding washer and dishwasher to existing breaker. No Dryer. Unsure if it can handle

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I currently have a 3 family where I am looking to install compact washing machine and a dishwasher for all 3 floors. It is an older building. Will be going with permits.

The first floor main panel is 40 amps with aluminium wire gauge 6 going to a sub panel. The subpanel has some room. It look like on the subpanel total amps is 290 when i add it all up.

Would I be able to upgrade the main panel from 40 to 50 amps and would it be able to handle an additonal washer and dishwasher. Currently the apartment has fridge, 2 AC, and lighing with two ceiling fans.

2nd and 3rd floor have a 50 amps main panel with alumin wire again the wire is 6 guage. Has additional spaces on subpanel. Has 1 fridge, 4 AC and 3 Ceiling fans and room lights.

I have attached pics of the first floor and second floor breaker.

Thanks for your help.

Pooja.[image: 1st Floor Panel Info][image: 1st Floor Panel]
[image: 2nd Floor Panel Info][image: 2nd Floor Panel][image: 2nd Floor Sub Panel]

Comment: Where are the "house loads" of this building currently fed from? (things like exterior lights and whatnot)  Can you supply photos of the building's metering/main breaker setup, for that matter?

Comment: Sure I am currently away til Monday to take the photos. The exterior lights are you referring to common lights if so that a separate box and is controlled by a separate main panel downstairs. Each apartment and the common building election have it own main box.

Comment: The wire coming in from the meter is gauge 8

Comment: Can you post photos of the main box for the common building lights/etc?

Comment: Caution with aluminum wire: it oxidizes with time, creating a high-resistance connection which can cause a fire. There are special connectors and oxidation-preventing chemicals that should be used. See https://www.cpsc.gov/s3fs-public/516.pdf

Comment: @DrMoishePippik -- feeders are a different story as loadcenter and breaker lugs are pretty uniformly dual-rated for aluminum and copper wire

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Sure will post the pics this Monday as I currently away till monday. Till I get the pics. There are 4 meters and the wire coming in from each are gauge 8 aluminium going to each main panel.There are 4 main panel. Common and separate for each apartment.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1lvTYN1uoDz93aTo8GhTxBXPiVfa4SQZv link of all pics

Comment: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1lvTYN1uoDz93aTo8GhTxBXPiVfa4SQZv

Comment: Are the last few photos in your Google Drive album photos of the house loads panel? What loads does that panel serve?  Furthermore, can you provide photos of the labeling on that panel, if present?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Just labeled all pics. These are the main panels in the basement coming directly from the meter. The posted pics are the subpanels in the apartment.

Comment: @pooja -- got your labeled photos.  What loads does that house (common) loads panel serve?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Common Load panel server. 5 Lights and hotwater heater and boiler and few outlets. Thats it. Nothing connected to outlet. All lights are LED.

Comment: @pooja -- how many HP is the boiler's circulator pump?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Regarding HP of boiler pump that I will need to check. I have a feeling the label may have gotten worn out.